# Alternative to struts TextTag in spring or jsp custom tag

Tags: java, tags

In struts custom tags we can generate HTML elements like <input> using TextTag.
Do we have any alternate to this in spring or jsp custom tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I digged more and here are my findings.

In Spring we can extend InputTag for customize results but limitation is element that you are specifying for value of input tag should be in commandBean. Otherwise will throw Bind error.

Second option is to create a JSP Tag with all flexibility, you can take some of implementation form InputTag and it works gr8.

I used second option.

Answer (score 0):

[spring mvc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-formtaglib-formtag) has `<form:input>` which has similar features as `<s:input>` in struts

Comment: no I have to create a custom tag that will take care of &lt;input&gt; creation and currency symbol placing basis on locale.